# This format (pgm) is unknown to imread

Tags: mahotas

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from os import walk,path
import numpy as np
import mahotas as mh
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
mh.imread('1.pgm')
```

Unable to read a PGM image in mahotas,the error infomation is 'RuntimeError: This format (pgm) is unknown to imread'

Comment: so, what is your question? And: the error says *exactly* what's wrong, so use a different file format, or a different reader.

Comment: Please read the [How to ask a good question section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)